# What is said about getting good deeds when helping sick parents?

Tags: parents, deeds, reward, sick

My mother was very sick so I had to stay and sleep in the hospital for a few days and help her with walking, going to the bathroom, calling the nurse, trying to feed her,...etc. She is much better now and we are home. What kind of rewards will I earn for helping her? What is said about getting good deeds when helping sick parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah brother. Glad to hear that your mother is getting better now. You have taken a good care for her.

To answer your question brother, taking care of sick parents has been highlighted in many part of the quran. It is more likely to be the responsibility of the child then just good deeds to the parents. The word of the Almighty Allah :

> (17:23) "Your Lord has decreed:25 (i) Do not worship any but Him;26
>   (ii) **Be good to your parents; and should both or any one of them
>   attain old age with you, do not say to them even "fie" neither chide
>   them, but speak to them with respect" - (al-Isra’:23)**

Speaking of rewards, taking care of our parents is consider as Jihad. You will regain happiness, serenity, wellness and burden-free lifestyle just to name a few (*In sha Allah*).
The Prophet's Companion, Abdullah bin Amru bin 'Ash, said:

> "One day a man approached the Messenger of Allah, asked for
>   permission to have a jihad with His Majesty. Then the Prophet asked
>   him:" Is your parents still alive? , they are still alive. "The
>   Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) said:" In your parents is
>   the value of jihad.

Therefore my brother, you have done a good job in taking care of your parents. A person who is able to be with or serve both parents is consider to be a very lucky person. This is because, the Prophet (saws) once said that a despicable person is the one who has the chances to be with his parents but that opportunity does not allow him to enter heaven. Again brother, *in sha Allah* we both will take good care to our parents one day just like how they treat us when we were small.

Answer (score 0):

What do they say about doing good deeds when helping sick parents?
As you know, parents are the best assets of life that God has commanded, so you should always ask God for help. And do not consider anything other than His pleasure, for the believers are like this.
Know this for sure that God will reward you for what you do; It will give you a reward that you never expected: And He provides for him from where he does not expect, and whoever trusts in God, suffices his command ”(Divorce, 3)
Although it is difficult to take care of the elderly, but patience in the face of this hardship will put you among the patient, for God has provided all the rewards and rewards for the patient: “O you who believe! ; O you who believe! Get help from patience, perseverance and prayer! For God is with the steadfast ”(Baqara, 153)

Ref.: https://hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/63980/