# Sometimes my parents are yelling and angry with me for no reason

Tags: sin, parents, anger

Selam alejkum.

I wanted to ask something releated to my parents that concern me to much. I love my parents very much and i try to respect them in any way possible. I know that Quran and our prophet Muhamed a.s said that we should respect our parents in any way possible and I try to do that for the sake of Allah.
My concern here is that whenever i make the most simple mistake possible such as letting the window open or even sometimes when i dont make any mistake at all they start yelling at me and become angry with me like its the end of of the world.
Even when they yell at me that way,I dont argue with them at all despite that I feel very angry inside for them yelling at me.
I fear allah and i wanted to know if made a sin behaving like this and if I have make a sin everytime my parents are yelling at me. I would really appriciate your answer with islamic arguments for this issue. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Salam what actually is your question? This is a Q&A site, what you've written here is just a long text about what happens to you, but you didn't actually ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

Walikum Assalam
Minor mistakes or doing things as you have free will to which are not harming anyone in real **is not sinful act.** you are not arguing is may increasing your reward and you may see that in here life too but keep that in mind those who face similar situation are usually end up doing same with others and then they suppose to get sin for hurting others , because they have scars on there souls. Usually i suggest them to find solution or some mutual understanding or move out for the benefit of there future self.

Answer (score 0):

Waalaikumsalam W.B.T,

Parents have always wanted the best for their children. I remembered my parents sometimes used to be mad at me too, just to make sure everything was the best for me. However, it has been stated inside the Quran to respect our parents in any possible ways.

The word of the Almighty Allah :

> (17:23) "Your Lord has decreed:25 (i) Do not worship any but Him;26
>   (ii) **Be good to your parents;** and should both or any one of them
>   attain old age with you, **do not say to them even "fie" neither chide
>   them, but speak to them with respect**" - (al-Isra’:23)

This explanation is almost the same with the one I have answered in [What is said about getting good deeds when helping sick parents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/58043/what-is-said-about-getting-good-deeds-when-helping-sick-parents/58051#58051) topic.

Hope this answers your questions.

Wallahualam.